# Magento 2 LESS - Unable to resolve the source file for ..., after deleting source file

Tags: magento2, less, grunt

I deleted a less file which I don't need anymore. I also removed the entry from **default_head_blocks.xml** so that it does not load anymore.

I searched my whole theme for **main.css** and removed all references to it.

But if I execute `grunt refresh` then I get **Unable to resolve the source file for frontend/company/base/de_DE/css/main.less**

So I executed `grunt clean && grunt refresh` but it makes no difference.

I also flushed all caches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to remove the entry ` in my **dev\tools\grunt\configs\local-themes.js**.

```
company: {
    area: 'frontend',
    name: 'hausfux/base',
    locale: 'de_DE',
    files: [
        'css/styles-m',
        'css/styles-l',
        'css/main'    // <-- REMOVE THIS
    ],
    dsl: 'less'
},
```

Now it works